# What is github actions' equivalent to circle ci's add_ssh_keys

Tags: github-actions, fastlane-match

In [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/add-ssh-key/), we need to `add_ssh_keys` to access another private repo that is not in the organization.

We are using `fastlane match` in the jobs so it is not simple checkout.

e.g.

```
- add_ssh_keys:
    fingerprints:
      - "SO:ME:FIN:G:ER:PR:IN:T"
```

How do you do that in GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [install SSH key action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/install-ssh-key). Just make sure you’re using a SSH git URL in your `Matchfile`, not a HTTPS URL.